# Cholesky factorization without calculating L

Tags: linear-algebra

The question asks if you can determine whether A, listed below, has a Cholestky $LL^T$$ factorization without compueting L. L is a lower triangular matrix with positive diagonal values.

One one had, I know A is a positive definite because all eigenvalues are positive. BUt I am having trouble relating this to Cholesky factorization.

$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 & 0 \\
-1 &  4 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: It is impossible to "Cholesky-factorize" a matrix which is not symmetrical.

Comment: @JeanMarie so all you need to say is that because matrix A is not symmetrical, you can not Cholesky factorize? Seems simple enough.

Comment: Yes, that's enough ...

Comment: @JeanMarie does it matter  if A is positive definite since the eigenvalues are positive? or is there no relation?

Comment: @AggrawalPuja Since $(LL^T)^T=L^{TT}L^T=LL^T$, if a matrix is not symmetric then it can't be equal to $LL^T$ for *any* matrix $L$.

Comment: "Positive-definiteness" is (besides symmetry) the other necessary condition for a Cholesky factorization to exist for the reason @egreg just gave.

Comment: @egreg makes sense, but I get stuck on was that the matrix was positive definite, I didnt think to check symmetry.

Comment: @egreg what happens if you replace, for example, a23 with a 2. That would mean the transpose is equal. How would you then calculate L? Just do basic Cholesky decomposition?

Comment: @AggrawalPuja I worked out a slightly different example in my answer, but it's essentially the same with the matrix you suggest.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for which your matrix $A$ doesn't have a Cholesky decomposition $A=LL^T$ is that it is not symmetric to begin with. Indeed, if we could find such a matrix $L$, then
$$
A^T=(LL^T)^T=L^{TT}L^T=LL^T=A
$$
which is impossible, because for your matrix $A\ne A^T$.

You are also making another mistake and it's better to discuss it. Consider the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -100 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This has positive eigenvalues, but
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -100 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}-99\\1\end{bmatrix}=-98<0
$$
So the fact that $A$ has positive eigenvalues does not imply that $x^TAx>0$ for $x\ne0$.

The notion of positive definedness is usually reserved for *symmetric* matrices, for which a necessary and sufficient condition is indeed having positive eigenvalues.

---

Consider instead
$$
B=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 & 0 \\
-1 &  4 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which is positive definite, as we will see. We can do Gaussian elimination:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 & 0 \\
-1 &  4 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 & 0 \\
0 &  7/2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
via $R_2\gets R_2-\frac{1}{2}R_1$, which means
$$
B=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1/2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 & 0 \\
0 &  7/2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1/2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 7/2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1/2 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and the Cholesky decomposition for $B$ is $B=LL^T$ where
$$
L=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1/2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt{2} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \sqrt{7/2} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \sqrt{2}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt{2} & 0 & 0 \\
-\sqrt{2}/2 & \sqrt{7/2} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \sqrt{2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So $B$ is positive definite, because $L$ is invertible.

One could also find an orthogonal matrix $P$ and a diagonal matrix with positive entries $D$ such that $B=PDP^T$, so we'd find $L$ by setting $L=P\sqrt{D}$, where $\sqrt{D}$ is the diagonal matrix with the positive square roots of the diagonal entries in $D$.

The advantage of the method with Gaussian elimination over using the diagonalization is that it's not necessary to know the eigenvalues.